# On a static call of a child function, why does the parent function run?

Tags: php, class, inheritance, static

Let's see this class construction:

```
class A
{
    public static function aa() { }
}

class B extends A
{
    public static function bb() { }
}
```

Here, `B:bb();` and `A:aa();` is valid. But why does `B:aa();` still work? Doesn't it means I directly call the `aa` method of `B`? Why does the inheritance and overriding work here?

Answer (score 5):

As `class B` *extends* `class A`, class B has every *protected* and *public* method that A has also.

By calling `B:aa()` the compiler looks if `B:aa()` is overridden in class B, and if not, it calls the parent class, which is class A in this case.

In Object Oriented Programming (OOP) extending a class is also know as inheritance, Class B inherits all the public and protected methods from class A

Comment: +1 for the explanation in the second paragraph